# NumberForm NumberPadding outside of NumberSigns formatting

Tags: output-formatting

I am getting an unexpected result with `NumberForm`'s `NumberPadding` option when specifying `NumberSigns` formatting option.

```
NumberForm[-60., {3, 1}, NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}, NumberSigns -> {{"(", ")"}, ""}]
(* (60.)0 *)
```

The above gives `(60.)0` when `(60.0)` is expected.  Have I missed something in my expectation? How do I specify the format with `NumberForm` (or any of the other `*Form` functions so that it works with both positive and negative numbers with padding?

That is, `-60.` would give `(60.0)` and `60.` would give `60.0` (leading and trailing space after padding for `{3,1}`).

Comment: Oh, I see it. Just saw the solution with the help of @Mr.Wizard post after I typed the edit.  I need `NumberSigns -> {{"(", ")"}, {" ", " "}}` along with `SignPadding -> True` from @Mr.Wizard post.

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem and that I was able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need the [`SignPadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SignPadding.html) option:

```
NumberForm[-60., {3, 1}, NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}, 
 NumberSigns -> {{"(", ")"}, ""}, SignPadding -> True]
```

> ```
> (60.0)
> ```

Comment: Close except that positive numbers come out with an extra `0`; `60.00` . The `SignPadding` does get it correct for negatives but not positives.  I am looking for `(60.0)` and `` 60.0 `` (leading and trailing space) for `-60.` and `60.`.  Perhaps I need to be clearer in the post. (+1)

Comment: I just saw the solution when typing the edit.  Your `SignPadding` addition was crucial.